# Execution hangs for string input greater than 1000 characters

Tags: c++, string, input

Code hangs for string input greater than 1000 characters
All characters in P & Q are lower-case English letters.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){

    // 1st example
    string p,q;
    cin >> p >> q;

    // 2nd example
    char p[1500],q[1500];
    scanf("%s",p);
    cin >> q ; 

    return 0;
   }
```

Both run fine for strings less than 1000 characters.
Both alternative examples break for strings greater than 1000 characters.
I just need a way to input strings of max 1500 chracters

**Edit:Turns out XCode was at fault. It works fine on the server**

Comment: I'm confused by your program fragment. Are the two examples alternatives? Which one works and which one breaks? Or are they to be executed in series? Then does it break during the first or second example?  Please post a **complete** program that demonstrates the error you are seeing. Please read http://sscce.org to find out why.

Comment: How do you provide the input? Perhaps the terminal hangs and not the program?

Comment: There is probably some fault in test file. It may be the case that you are reading more than required input, and the programs waits for it.

Comment: Post your edit as answer and mark it as such. That's ok here on SO.

Answer (score -2):

If you pass Unicode input to this, the buffers will overflow & you will crash.

**Edited to add:**

If you're lucky. Note that lowercase English Unicode characters are *still* two bytes each. If your input is from a file, you cannot tell by looking whether it's Unicode, you need to open it in a hex editor to be sure.

To test this, make the buffers twice as large as the input (`p[2001], q[2001]`).

But using static buffers is *the wrong way to do this*, `string` is the right way: the upper limit is something like 2^32 characters.

Comment: Well, at least, hopefully you crash.

Comment: How does that address the OP's problem?

Comment: All characters in P & Q are lower-case English letters.

Comment: @jwodder: he's saying his code crashes for long strings. I'm suggesting that if his long strings are Unicode, that would explain the crash.

Comment: Is there a limit of approx 1000 characters?

Comment: @egrunin Is there a way to read 1500 characters so that the buffers will not overflow

Comment: @user1301541: if you remove the last three lines, does it hang?

Comment: @egrunin yes, even after removing the last three lines it hangs